# Typescript array of functions and call

Tags: javascript, typescript

I trying to call a a function inside a array. I get an error message : ***The expression type { function } is not assignable to boolean.***

**Declaration:**

```
    public conditions: { (value: any): bool; }[] = [];
```

**Usage:**

```
    var myBool: bool = conditions["myKey"]("someParam");
```

Whats wrong here ? Do i need to cast here ?

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? They changed several things since release and I am asking, because `var conditions: { (value: any): bool; }[] = []; var myBool: bool = conditions["myKey"]("someParam");` compiles fine for me.

Comment: 0.8.3 using Webstorm 6 (its more restricted, what is not bad at all)

Comment: interesting, I am using an older version (0.8.1.1) with visual studio ... will upgrade to 0.8.3 to test it.

Answer (score 1):

This works in the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20conditions%3a%20%7B%20%28value%3a%20any%29%3a%20bool;%20%7D%5B%5D%20=%20%5B%5D;%0Avar%20myBool%3a%20bool%20=%20conditions%5B%22myKey%22%5D%28%22someParam%22%29;%0A%0A), which uses 0.8.3. Are you sure this is actually the code in question? Indexing an array by a string produces a value of type `any`, so the function invocation there is sort of irrelevant for type purposes since it will just produce an `any` as well.